# Does Microsoft Sql Server 2012 Data Quality Services support Oracle?

Tags: sql-server-2012, data-quality-services

Does anyone know if Data Quality Services in Sql Server 2012 can be used against Oracle databases to improve their quality? I've had a look around the Sql Server site and can't determine if it can or not.

Thanks,

Steve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to use Data Quality Services over Oracle DBs.

1. Via the DQS SSIS cleansing component - you can use this as part of an SSIS flow that retrieves the data from the Oracle DB, cleans it within the SSIS flow using the DQS component, and then sends it back to the Oracle DB.
2. Via the use of the Linked Server functionality of SQL Server. See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7540.accessing-your-data-on-remote-servers-for-dqs-operations-by-linking-servers.aspx for more information on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Elad, that's great. What edition of Sql Server 2012 is Linked Servers available in? Is it standard or BI or enterprise?

Comment: linked servers requires the Enterprise Edition of 2012 (here's a list of features) -- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ialonso/archive/2011/09/21/understanding-the-value-of-the-enterprise-edition-one-feature-at-a-time.aspx